# Choosing deployment options for aiohttp low level server

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Im absolutely lost with deployment options for my aiohttp server;
There are multiple ways to move service in production and I can't choose correct one:

1. systemd script/supervisord + api hour
   Cons: i don't understand how api hour works, it seems like ah take control of server's daemon coroutine, but my server's coro run (low lelev aiohttp server/connection handler)in asyncio.gather function with other coro (supervisor/states keeper's class forever run method) and it could be problematic to handle second coroutine with api hour
2. gunicorn same thoughs like at 1
3. nginx + unix socket +systemd script
   Cons: looking damn hard to deploy and support;
4. pure aiohttp server under systemd script:
   Cons: handling pid files, low performance(?)
   I'll be happy to see any thoughts about my problem, thanx!

My run function looks like:

```
def run():
    startTime = time.time()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s [ %(levelname)s ]: %(message)s")
    cfg = ConfigStore("server_config.cfg")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    logging.info("Starting server")
    db = DBProxyLayer.fabric(cfg("dbCredentials"))
    logging.info("DBLayer initialized {}".format(db))
    try:
        supervisor = QPSServerSupervisor(loop=loop, db=db, config=cfg)
        srvCoro = loop.create_server(lambda: QPSServer(
                    supervisor=supervisor, debug=False, keep_alive_on=False, loop=loop),
                    host=cfg("command_host"), port=cfg("command_port"))
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*(srvCoro, supervisor.startToServe())))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.critical("Server start failure {}\n{}".format(e, traceback.print_exc()))
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        logging.info("Server started for {0:.2f} seconds".format(time.time()-startTime))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)
        loop.close()
        sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: Options 1-3 are equal. I don't recommend running aiohttp server without reverse proxy for production usage

Comment: Thanx Andrew, could you share some expirience about deployment process? Which proxy to use, maybe some references?

Answer (score 0):

`loop.create_server` can take a `sock=` keyword to activate on a pre-existing socket.  My approach is

```
try:
    import systemd.daemon
except ImportError:
    def listeners(hosts, port):
        for host in hosts:
            _log.info("Starting server at %s on port %d", host, port)
            yield dict(host=host, port=port)
else:
    def listeners(hosts, port):
        daemon_fds = list(
            fd
            for fd in systemd.daemon.listen_fds()
            if systemd.daemon.is_socket_inet(
                fd,
                type=socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                listening=1,
            )
        )

        if len(daemon_fds) == 0:
            for host in hosts:
                _log.info("Starting server at %s on port %d", host, port)
                yield dict(host=host, port=port)
        else:
            _log.info("Starting server from systemd-provided file descriptors %r", daemon_fds)
            yield from (
                dict(sock=fd)
                for fd in daemon_fds
            )
```

Then in `run`, I loop over the `yield`ed dicts:

```
coros = []
for listener_args in listeners(hosts, port):
    coro = loop.create_server(factory, ssl=ssl_context, **listener_args)
    coros.append(coro)
coros.append(supervisor.startToServe())
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coros))
```